# Json mapping with variables Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

im mapping this Json:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 4,
    "count_total": 4,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 220,
            "type": "products",
            "slug": "jugo-de-naranja",
            "url": "http://localhost/?products=jugo-de-naranja",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "Jugo de Naranja",
            "title_plain": "Jugo de Naranja",
            "content": "",
            "excerpt": "",
            "date": "2014-03-12 17:34:01",
            "modified": "2014-03-12 17:34:01",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 26,
                    "slug": "juices-2",
                    "title": "Juices",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 2
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "arturocalvo",
                "name": "arturocalvo",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "arturocalvo",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "closed",
            "custom_fields": {
                "product_type": [
                    "bebida"
                ],
                "tipo_de_bebida": [
                    "jugo"
                ],
                "jugo_0_size": [
                    "m"
                ],
                "jugo_0_real_id": [
                    "22"
                ],
                "jugo_0_price": [
                    "20"
                ],
                "jugo_0_sucursal": [
                    "2"
                ],
                "jugo": [
                    "1"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

but the problem I have is that i need to map tipo_de_bebida in the custom fields part, for this product class

```
@interface Products : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * productType;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * productCategory;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * locationId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * realId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * price;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * size;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * mod;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * temp;
```

the mapping will go with product type, because I need to map all the other attributes, but my problem is that I need to map other products in the same class, but the other products fields

```
"product_type": [
                    "bebida"
                ],
                "tipo_de_bebida": [
                    "jugo"
```

are named different, thus in the fields
    jugo_0_size 
    jugo_0_real_id
    jugo_0_price
    jugo_0_sucursal
the "jugo" part changes for "platillo" or "cafe", i have tried to pull the json in an Array to get a string with the different texts, but my seem to not be working, here is the code

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    baseURL];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* productJson = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:jsonData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSString * key in productJson){

        [productArray addObject:key];
    }
```

can somebody tell me what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to put the keys or the objects of the dictionary in the array. because in both cases your for-loop is wrong.

Comment: Assuming the indentation of your JSON is correct, "tipo_de_bebida" is an element in the "custom_fields" object (dictionary) which is in the objects (dictionaries) which are elements of the "posts" array.

Comment: Your code above will add the "status", "count", "count_total", "pages", and "posts" keys to "productArray".  Is this what you really want??

Comment: Hint: Do it one step at a time.  Access `productJson` to get "posts", which will be an NSArray.  Iterate through the array, where each element will be an NSDictionary containing "id", "type", "categories" ... "custom_fields".  NSLog what you have there to be sure you're where you think you should be.  With each array entry reference the dictionary and extract the data you want.